# Python / Flask / SQLAlchemy - Tables not being created

Tags: python, visual-studio-code, flask, flask-sqlalchemy

I'm new to programing and just finished a few classes and courses, now on the way to deploy my first app.

I'm using Python and Flask and FlaskSQLAlchemy. I'm trying to create the tables, but can't.

Any ideas on fixes?

When i run the app, the fallback db gets created but empty.

**My app.py**

```
import os
from flask import Flask, render_template
from flask_sqlalchemy import SQLAlchemy

db = SQLAlchemy()
app = Flask(__name__)
app.config.from_object('config.Config')
db.init_app(app)

from models import Base, Gender, ActivityLevel, KitesurfingExpertise, User, Equipment, EquipmentType, Size, WindCondition, Brand, FormEntry

with app.app_context():
    db.create_all()
```

**My models.py**

```
from sqlalchemy.ext.declarative import declarative_base
from sqlalchemy import Column, Integer, String, ForeignKey, Date, Float
from sqlalchemy.orm import relationship

Base = declarative_base()

class Gender(Base):
    __tablename__ = 'Gender'

    id = Column('GenderID', Integer, primary_key=True)
    description = Column('Description', String, nullable=False)

    users = relationship("User", backref="gender")


class ActivityLevel(Base):
    __tablename__ = 'ActivityLevel'

    id = Column('ActivityLevelID', Integer, primary_key=True)
    description = Column('Description', String, nullable=False)

    users = relationship("User", backref="activity_level")


class KitesurfingExpertise(Base):
    __tablename__ = 'KitesurfingExpertise'

    id = Column('ExpertiseID', Integer, primary_key=True)
    description = Column('Description', String, nullable=False)

    users = relationship("User", backref="expertise")


class User(Base):
    __tablename__ = 'User'

    id = Column('UserID', Integer, primary_key=True)
    gender_id = Column('GenderID', Integer, ForeignKey('Gender.GenderID'))
    dob = Column('DateOfBirth', Date, nullable=False)
    height = Column('HeightInches', Float, nullable=False)
    weight = Column('WeightLbs', Float, nullable=False)
    activity_level_id = Column('ActivityLevelID', Integer, ForeignKey('ActivityLevel.ActivityLevelID'))
    expertise_id = Column('ExpertiseID', Integer, ForeignKey('KitesurfingExpertise.ExpertiseID'))

    # Relationship
    form_entries = relationship("FormEntry", backref="user")

class Equipment(Base):
    __tablename__ = 'Equipment'

    id = Column('EquipmentID', Integer, primary_key=True)
    description = Column('Description', String, nullable=False)

    # Relationship
    types = relationship("EquipmentType", back_populates="equipment")
    form_entries = relationship("FormEntry", backref="equipment")


class EquipmentType(Base):
    __tablename__ = 'EquipmentType'

    id = Column('TypeID', Integer, primary_key=True)
    equipment_id = Column('EquipmentID', Integer, ForeignKey('Equipment.EquipmentID'))
    description = Column('Description', String, nullable=False)

    # Relationship
    equipment = relationship("Equipment", back_populates="types")
    form_entries = relationship("FormEntry", backref="equipment_type")


class Size(Base):
    __tablename__ = 'Size'

    id = Column('SizeID', Integer, primary_key=True)
    description = Column('Description', String, nullable=False)

    form_entries = relationship("FormEntry", backref="size")


class WindCondition(Base):
    __tablename__ = 'WindCondition'

    id = Column('ConditionID', Integer, primary_key=True)
    description = Column('Description', String, nullable=False)

    form_entries = relationship("FormEntry", backref="wind_condition")


class Brand(Base):
    __tablename__ = 'Brand'

    id = Column('BrandID', Integer, primary_key=True)
    description = Column('Description', String, nullable=False)

    form_entries = relationship("FormEntry", backref="brand")


class FormEntry(Base):
    __tablename__ = 'FormEntry'

    id = Column('EntryID', Integer, primary_key=True)
    user_id = Column('UserID', Integer, ForeignKey('User.UserID'))
    equipment_id = Column('EquipmentID', Integer, ForeignKey('Equipment.EquipmentID'))
    type_id = Column('TypeID', Integer, ForeignKey('EquipmentType.TypeID'))
    size_id = Column('SizeID', Integer, ForeignKey('Size.SizeID'))
    condition_id = Column('ConditionID', Integer, ForeignKey('WindCondition.ConditionID'))
    brand_id = Column('BrandID', Integer, ForeignKey('Brand.BrandID'))
    model = Column('Model', String, nullable=False)
    
    # Relationships (Note: relationships for user will be defined in the user model)
    equipment = relationship("Equipment")
    equipment_type = relationship("EquipmentType")
    size = relationship("Size")
    wind_condition = relationship("WindCondition")
    brand = relationship("Brand")
```

**My config.py:**

```
import os

class Config:
    SQLALCHEMY_DATABASE_URI = os.environ.get('JAWSDB_MARIA_URL', 'sqlite:///fallback.db')
    SQLALCHEMY_TRACK_MODIFICATIONS = False
```

They are on the same level on the project folder.

**

> UPDATE 1

**

I have updated my models.py to be precisely using FlaskSQLAlchemy (I hope):

```
from flask_sqlalchemy import SQLAlchemy

db = SQLAlchemy()

class Gender(db.Model):
    __tablename__ = 'gender'
    id = db.Column('gender_id', db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    description = db.Column('description', db.String, nullable=False)
    users = db.relationship("User", backref="gender")

class ActivityLevel(db.Model):
    __tablename__ = 'activity_level'
    id = db.Column('activity_level_id', db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    description = db.Column('description', db.String, nullable=False)
    users = db.relationship("User", backref="activity_level")

class KitesurfingExpertise(db.Model):
    __tablename__ = 'kitesurfing_expertise'
    id = db.Column('expertise_id', db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    description = db.Column('description', db.String, nullable=False)
    users = db.relationship("User", backref="expertise")

class User(db.Model):
    __tablename__ = 'user'
    id = db.Column('user_id', db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    gender_id = db.Column(db.Integer, db.ForeignKey('gender.gender_id'))
    dob = db.Column('date_of_birth', db.Date, nullable=False)
    height = db.Column('height_inches', db.Float, nullable=False)
    weight = db.Column('weight_lbs', db.Float, nullable=False)
    activity_level_id = db.Column(db.Integer, db.ForeignKey('activity_level.activity_level_id'))
    expertise_id = db.Column(db.Integer, db.ForeignKey('kitesurfing_expertise.expertise_id'))

class Equipment(db.Model):
    __tablename__ = 'equipment'
    id = db.Column('equipment_id', db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    description = db.Column('description', db.String, nullable=False)
    types = db.relationship("EquipmentType", backref="equipment")

class EquipmentType(db.Model):
    __tablename__ = 'equipment_type'
    id = db.Column('type_id', db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    equipment_id = db.Column(db.Integer, db.ForeignKey('equipment.equipment_id'))
    description = db.Column('description', db.String, nullable=False)

class Size(db.Model):
    __tablename__ = 'size'
    id = db.Column('size_id', db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    description = db.Column('description', db.String, nullable=False)

class WindCondition(db.Model):
    __tablename__ = 'wind_condition'
    id = db.Column('condition_id', db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    description = db.Column('description', db.String, nullable=False)

class Brand(db.Model):
    __tablename__ = 'brand'
    id = db.Column('brand_id', db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    description = db.Column('description', db.String, nullable=False)

class FormEntry(db.Model):
    __tablename__ = 'form_entry'
    id = db.Column('entry_id', db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    user_id = db.Column(db.Integer, db.ForeignKey('user.user_id'))
    equipment_id = db.Column(db.Integer, db.ForeignKey('equipment.equipment_id'))
    type_id = db.Column(db.Integer, db.ForeignKey('equipment_type.type_id'))
    size_id = db.Column(db.Integer, db.ForeignKey('size.size_id'))
    condition_id = db.Column(db.Integer, db.ForeignKey('wind_condition.condition_id'))
    brand_id = db.Column(db.Integer, db.ForeignKey('brand.brand_id'))
    model = db.Column('model', db.String, nullable=False)
```

Also, updated and tested my app.py, when defining a single sample model on the file itself, the table get's created, but when importing (see #commented line) no tables are created:

Relevant slice:

```
from flask import Flask, render_template
from flask_sqlalchemy import SQLAlchemy
import os

# Criar a extensão
db = SQLAlchemy()

# Criar o app Flask
app = Flask(__name__)

# Configurar a URI do SQLite, relativo à pasta da instância do app.
app.config["SQLALCHEMY_DATABASE_URI"] = "sqlite:///kitedatabase.db"
app.config["SQLALCHEMY_TRACK_MODIFICATIONS"] = False  # Para evitar warnings

# Inicializar o app com a extensão
db.init_app(app)

# Importar os modelos após inicializar o app e a extensão db
# from models import Gender, ActivityLevel, KitesurfingExpertise, User, Equipment, EquipmentType, Size, WindCondition, Brand, FormEntry

class Gender(db.Model):
    __tablename__ = 'gender'
    id = db.Column('gender_id', db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    description = db.Column('description', db.String, nullable=False)
    users = db.relationship("User", backref="gender")
```

Any ideas? Thanks everyone.

Answer (score 1):

Solved removing circular references:

**created a setup.py:**

```
# setup.py
from flask import Flask
from flask_sqlalchemy import SQLAlchemy

app = Flask(__name__)
db = SQLAlchemy(app)
```

**Imported things to models.py:**

```
# models.py
from setup import db

classes definitions...
```

**Brought it all together to app.py:**

```
# app.py
from setup import app, db
from models import Gender, ActivityLevel, ...

if __name__ == '__main__':
    with app.app_context():
        db.create_all()
    app.run(debug=True)
```

Thanks for the lead on the mixing @snakecharmerb!